# IIS7(v4.0)-Hosting BlogEngine.Net v3 under an MVC 4 Site - Error "Could not load file or assembly"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, virtualhost, blogengine.net

I have created an MVC 4 application and hosted it in my local IIS. It's running fine. I also downloaded the latest BlogEngine v3 source and did some custom changes and hosted that as an independent site. That's working fine as well. The problem is I want to  host the BlogEngine as an application under my MVC Site, with virtual path "/devblog". I am getting the following

```css
body {
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: .7em;
  color: black;
}
p {
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-weight: normal;
  color: black;
  margin-top: -5px
}
b {
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  margin-top: -5px
}
H1 {
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18pt;
  color: red
}
H2 {
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: maroon
}
pre {
  font-family: "Consolas", "Lucida Console", Monospace;
  font-size: 11pt;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  line-height: 14pt
}
.marker {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.version {
  color: gray;
}
.error {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.expandable {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: navy;
  cursor: hand;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
  pre {
    width: 440px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  pre {
    width: 280px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Could not load file or assembly 'MVC4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

</head>

<body bgcolor="white">

  <span><H1>Server Error in '/devblog' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

                    <h2> <i>Could not load file or assembly 'MVC4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</i> </h2></span>

  <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

                    <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

                    <br><br>

                    <b> Exception Details: </b>System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Pleatco3' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.<br><br>

                    <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

                    <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
                       <tr>
                          <td>
                              <code>

        An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                          </td>
                       </tr>
                    </table>

                    <br>

                    <b>Assembly Load Trace:</b> The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MVC4' could not be loaded.<br><br>

                    <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
                       <tr>
                          <td>
                              <code><pre>

        Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
        Running under executable  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
        --- A detailed error log follows. 

        === Pre-bind state information ===
        LOG: DisplayName = MVC4
         (Partial)
        WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
        WRN: Assembly Name: Pleatco3 | Domain ID: 2
        WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
        WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
        WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
        WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
        WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
        LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/ProKrishna/MVC/MVC4/MVC4/blog/BlogEngine.NET 3.1 (source)/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.NET/
        LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\ProKrishna\MVC\MVC4\Mvc4\blog\BlogEngine.NET 3.1 (source)\BlogEngine\BlogEngine.NET\bin
        Calling assembly : (Unknown).
        ===
        LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
        LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\ProKrishna\MVC\MVC4\MVC4\blog\BlogEngine.NET 3.1 (source)\BlogEngine\BlogEngine.NET\web.config
        LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
        LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
        LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
        LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/devblog/154bbd48/3b9b3677/MVC4.DLL.
        LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/devblog/154bbd48/3b9b3677/Pleatco3/MVC4.DLL.
        LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/ProKrishna/MVC/MVC4/MVC4/blog/BlogEngine.NET 3.1 (source)/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.NET/bin/MVC4.DLL.
        LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/ProKrishna/MVC/MVC4/MVC4/blog/BlogEngine.NET 3.1 (source)/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.NET/bin/Pleatco3/MVC4.DLL.
        LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/devblog/154bbd48/3b9b3677/MVC4.EXE.
        LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/devblog/154bbd48/3b9b3677/MVC4/MVC4.EXE.
        LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/ProKrishna/MVC/MVC4/MVC4/blog/BlogEngine.NET 3.1 (source)/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.NET/bin/MVC4.EXE.
        LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/ProKrishna/MVC/MVC4/MVC4/blog/BlogEngine.NET 3.1 (source)/BlogEngine/BlogEngine.NET/bin/Pleatco3/Pleatco3.EXE.
        </pre></code>

                          </td>
                       </tr>
                    </table>

                    <br>

                    <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

                    <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
                       <tr>
                          <td>
                              <code><pre>

        [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly MVC4 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
           System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
           System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
           System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
           System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
           System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
           System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
           System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

        [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly MVC4; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
           System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
           System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +57
           System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
           System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
           System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean&amp; isRefAssemblyLoaded) +285
           System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
           System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521

        [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly MVC4 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
           System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9950728
           System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
           System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
        </pre></code>

                          </td>
                       </tr>
                    </table>

                    <br>

                    <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

                    <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237

                    </font>

</body>

</html>
<!-- 
        [FileNotFoundException]: Could not load file or assembly &#39;Pleatco3&#39; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
           at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
           at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
        [ConfigurationErrorsException]: Could not load file or assembly &#39;Pleatco3&#39; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
           at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
           at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
           at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
           at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
           at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded)
           at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
           at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
        [HttpException]: Could not load file or assembly &#39;Pleatco3&#39; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
           at System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
           at System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
           at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
        -->
```

```
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing a few assemblies/DLLs that should be in the bin folder.

Comment: but the same application works absolutely fine when hosted as a an independent site..